# Upgrading to 3.7.26 causes tempnam() error from twig's FilesystemCache.php

Tags: templating, cache, composer, upgrades

I am upgrading a Craft project that I have been neglecting for a little bit too long. I am upgrading to 3.7.26 from 3.4.25; on top of this, I am upgrading from PHP 7.1 to PHP 7.4.

I'm also updating a variety of plugins on top of this as well. Attached is my composer.json file below.

After nuking my vendor file, completing the `php craft update all`, and installing new required dependencies (multibyte string, ext-curl, etc), I'm getting the following error.

```
## PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory

line 64: $tmpFile = tempnam($dir, basename($key));
```

I've tried nuking my vendor folder again, trying in different browsers, updating composer, searching SO a bunch, and I'm not sure where to check next.

Any thoughts would be really helpful, thanks.

My composer.json file:

```
{
  "require": {
    "anubarak/craft-relabel": "2.0.2",
    "born05/craft-twofactorauthentication": "2.10.0",
    "carlcs/craft-redactorcustomstyles": "3.0.4",
    "craftcms/cms": "^3.7.26",
    "craftcms/contact-form": "2.2.7",
    "craftcms/google-cloud": "1.4.1",
    "craftcms/mailgun": "2.0.0",
    "craftcms/redactor": "2.8.8",
    "doublesecretagency/craft-cpcss": "2.4.0",
    "doublesecretagency/craft-cpjs": "2.4.0",
    "ether/logs": "3.0.5",
    "ether/seo": "^3.1.0",
    "marionnewlevant/snitch": "3.0.4.1",
    "remcoov/avataaars": "1.0.1",
    "spicyweb/craft-fieldlabels": "1.3.2",
    "spicyweb/craft-neo": "2.12.1",
    "trendyminds/visor": "3.0.1",
    "unionco/calendarize": "^1.2",
    "verbb/field-manager": "2.2.4",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^3.4.0",
    "whoisjuan/craft-color-mixer": "1.0.9"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-shell": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\": "modules/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.4"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprised you weren't getting this on 7.1 as well since it appears that is when that notice was added: https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues/1108#issuecomment-272012827

Regardless, this doesn't appear to be a Craft or Composer issue, but more of a PHP/server configuration one.

There are a couple of things to try in here as a starting point: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74189